# Showing a fancy tag list on git

Tags: git

I have the following git log alias:

```
 lo = log --pretty=format:\"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]\" --graph --date=short -n 8
```

How can I display a list of all the git tags with a fancy format like the above, instead of just the tag name like the `git tag` call does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a neat answer to this, but you could create a shell alias for something like this:

```
for t in $(git tag -l)
do
    printf "%-16s" $t
    echo `git show -s --pretty=format:"%h %ad | %s%d [%an]" --date=short $t^{}`
done
```

... which on the main git repository would produce output like:

```
v1.7.9          828ea97 2012-01-27 | Git 1.7.9 (v1.7.9) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9-rc0      eac2d83 2012-01-06 | Git 1.7.9-rc0 (v1.7.9-rc0) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9-rc1      6db5c6e 2012-01-12 | Git 1.7.9-rc1 (v1.7.9-rc1) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9-rc2      bddcefc 2012-01-18 | Git 1.7.9-rc2 (v1.7.9-rc2) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.1        90020e3 2012-02-14 | Git 1.7.9.1 (v1.7.9.1) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.2        78f4c9f 2012-02-22 | Git 1.7.9.2 (v1.7.9.2) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.3        69f4e08 2012-03-05 | Git 1.7.9.3 (v1.7.9.3) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.4        a460348 2012-03-12 | Git 1.7.9.4 (v1.7.9.4) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.5        8ced9c9 2012-03-26 | Git 1.7.9.5 (v1.7.9.5) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.6        cb2ed32 2012-04-02 | Git 1.7.9.6 (v1.7.9.6) [Junio C Hamano]
v1.7.9.7        d0f1ea6 2012-04-26 | Git 1.7.9.7 (v1.7.9.7) [Junio C Hamano]
```

The non-obvious bit of that for me is the `^{}` suffix on the tag name, which means to dereference any tag object to find the commit it points to, as described on the [`git rev-parse` man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions).

Comment: This is great! Would be greater if it could be made to list newest tags first: `git tag` seems not to have such an option, do I have to sort them with another command, or I missed something?

Comment: @Lohoris: I don't think that would be well-defined for `git tag -l` - tags can point to anything: tag objects, commit objects, blob objects, etc.  Blobs, for example, don't have dates attached.  A simple solution would be to just change `%ad` to `%ad:%ai` and sort based on the third column.

Comment: Thanks for %ai, I searched a lot for it but couldn't find it anywhere!

Comment: Changing the "for" line to `for t in $(git branch -l|cut -b3-)` **does the same thing for branches**.